# What i need to install python 2.5 on SCO 5.0.5

Tags: python, unix

I would love to install python2.5 on sco unix, and am wondering anybody who has attempted to do this?

Comment: its Stable! Very little resources(96mb ram) and over 150 users connecting to it! very core apps running there.

Comment: @gath: I can run, say, freebsd on 4MB ram and have thousands of users. Not sure what that means.

Comment: Unwind's answer has the right response... are there any errors you can give us that indicates why this hasn't worked for you? If not, then spend the 5 minutes necessary to try and build it and let us know what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Did you already try the [standard source instructions](http://www.python.org/download/source/), and fail? If so, I guess it would be useful to mention what failed. This is almost a non-programming question, as it's phrased now ...